# How to solve “bad interpreter: No such file or directory” error in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, crashlytics

I tried Fabric for crashlytics in my iOS app.I installed Fabric via cocoapod.
My run script look like this
**"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run" 5fff878b48f0c239da398853befb1559ccdd7717 3a66fd28662c398358b9510f79a16f0fe7f6a89f826213f0c5962e8540e4bb8e**

But I got the following error.

**Pods/Fabric/run: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory**

How to solve this issue? Please help me

Comment: did you tried to delete pod directory and install pod again?

Comment: You are right.Thanks

Comment: Great...!!! posted my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete **Pods** directory from your project and run `pod install` command again.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue using the following way.

I added the following command in my terminal

$ pod deintegrate

$ pod install

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have moved the project from a Windows machine to Mac and it contains carriage returns '\r'.

```
brew install dos2unix

find . -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;
```